# [Smarty] Передача переменной в шаблон

Tags: php, smarty

Здравствуйте!
Как просто передать переменную в нужный мне файлик .tpl?

Я делаю вот так:

```
$content = $template->fetch("news.tpl");
$template->assign('content',$content);
$template->assign('row',$row);

$template->display($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/templates/default/main.tpl");
```

Тоесть, я передаю переменную row в файлик main.tpl. Передается переменная когда срабатывает вот эта строчка.

А мне нужно тут же передать эту переменную в файл news.tpl, тоесть передать ее и main.tpl и в news.tpl. Она мне нужна в news.tpl поскольку я юзаю:

```
$content = $template->fetch("news.tpl");
$template->assign('content',$content);
```

Как такое сделать?
Заранее благодарен.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$template->assign('row', $row);
```

Вынесите повыше

```
$template->fetch("news.tpl");
```

Т.е.:

```
$template->assign('row', $row);
$content = $template->fetch("news.tpl");
$template->assign('content', $content);
$template->display($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/templates/default/main.tpl");
```

Comment: Нет, так не работает.
Все осталось неизменным.
Еще варианты?

Comment: А нет, данная структура в общем работает. Только вот в моем варианте не хочет. Может что-то не так с циклом.
{foreach $row as $key => $items}
 <div class="centerblock">
  <div class="headertxt">{$items.id}</div>
  <div class="contentinfo">{$items.name}</div>
  
   {$items.story}

 </div>
{/foreach}

Comment: Проблема решена!